# What is wrong with this recursion method?

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Recursion
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter n to start: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers from 1 to " + n + ": " +new Recursion().sumUpTo(n));
    }
}
/**
 * Computes the sum of a range of numbers
 * 
 * @param n an integer
 * @return the sum of n range
 */
    public int sumUpTo(int num){
        if (num == 0) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return (num + sumUpTo(num-1))
        }
    }
```

This should be a very simple method, I know, but I can't seem to get it to compile.  I keep getting "class, interface, or enum expected" on the public int sumUpTo(int num) line.  This is the method that performs the actual computations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: method `sumUpTo()` is outside of the class

Comment: Dem brackets. Dem. Brackets.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things :

- Your method is declared outside of the class
- Missing semicolon on the line with your recursive call

Comment: Yay, someone picked up on the missing semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

Move your sumUpTo method inside the class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Recursion
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter n to start: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers from 1 to " + n + ": " +new Recursion().sumUpTo(n));
    }

    /**
     * Computes the sum of a range of numbers
     * 
     * @param n an integer
     * @return the sum of n range
     */
    public int sumUpTo(int num){
        if (num == 0) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return (num + sumUpTo(num-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a close reason _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."_ and you have the access on it. This kind of question really won't help future readers. (ah I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: And yet it will help the OP.

Comment: downvoted because it won't compile. I guess

Comment: It compiles and works.

Comment: Ahh I seee. :D But sadly its not me

Answer (score -1):

You should be new to Object Oriented Programming. In Java a function(method) must be inside(belong) to a class. You either put public int sumUpTo(int num) inside public class Recursion or you can create another class and put it in there. But remember there should be only one public class inside a file.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, everything must be inside of a class. Simply move your method to within the curly braces of the class and it should work.

The error `class, interface, or enum expected` is quite self-explained! It encountered code that wasn't inside of a class, inteface, or enum, and it wasn't expecting that, because that shouldn't happen!

In case you need to see what I mean:

```
public class Recursion {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    // your code here...
    }

    // Where your method should have gone.

}
```

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to accept an answer if it answers your question.